# How to style/reference a html tag like <h1 anyname>Text</h1> without any class or id specified within it?

Tags: css

How can I reference a html element like `<h1 anyname>Text</h1>` in CSS, if there is no `class` or `id` specified within it? Is there an option?

`.h1 {...}` is of course valid for all, but I only want to style "h1 anyname".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) — square brackets with the attribute name.

```css
h1[anyname] {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp
`h1[anyname] {  /*** your style ***/ }`